# Не идентифицируется переменная python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class regform(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_regform()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("For Stas")
# Подключаем кнопку "Регистрация"
        self.ui.rButton.clicked.connect(self.rButton)
# Подключаем текстовые поля и выпадающий список
        self.ui.name.textChanged[str].connect(self.NameFunction)
        self.ui.password.textChanged[str].connect(self.PasswordFunction)
        self.ui.codeorganization.textChanged[str].connect(self.CodeFunction)
        self.ui.rang.activated[str].connect(self.RangFunction)
    name1 = ""
    pass1 = ""
    rang1 = ""
    code1 = ""
    # Функция поля "Введите Ваше Имя и Фамилию"
    def NameFunction(self, namesql):
        global name1
        name1 = namesql

    # Функция поля "Введите Ваш пароль"
    def PasswordFunction(self, passsql):
        global pass1
        pass1 = passsql

    # Функция поля "Выберите должность"
    def RangFunction(self, rangsql):
        global rang1
        rang1 = rangsql

    # Функция поля "Код организации"
    def CodeFunction(self, codesql):
        global code1
        code1 = codesql


    # Функция кнопки "Зарегистрироваться"
    def rButton(self):
        errors = []
        # Проверки на пустоту заполнения полей
        if not name1:
            errors.append("Введите Ваше Имя и Фамилию")
            print(errors[0])

        if not pass1:
            errors.append("Введите Ваш пароль")

        if not rang1:
            errors.append("Выберите Вашу должность")

        if not code1:
            errors.append("Введите код вашей Организации")
```

Проблема в том, что не идентифицируется переменная name1, pass1, rang1, code1 помогите, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: В функции `rButton` нет переменной с именем `name1`, но вы пытаетесь к ней обращаться.

Comment: Используйте не глобальные переменные, а переменные объекта. Соответственно `self.name1 = namesql` и `if not self.name1:`.

Comment: @0andriy Исправил по вашему `AttributeError: 'regform' object has no attribute 'name1':` Вот такая ошибка. RegForm - виджет забыл указать, что работаю с pyqt5

Comment: Ну вы вообще чего-то странное понаписали в коде. Пишите в `__init__()` по-человечески, а именно — `self.name1 = ""`. Потом всё, что я сказал, и поудаляйте эти ужастные `global`. Вообще,  запустите на свой скрипт *pylint*.

Comment: @0andriy Благодарю, всё заработало

Answer (score 0):

На уровне модуля определите переменную `name1`, чтобы ваша функция `rButton()` познакомилась с этим именем уже во время её дефиниции:

```
name1 = ""                                              # Добавлено

# Функция поля "Введите Ваше Имя и Фамилию"
    def NameFunction(self, namesql):
        global name1
        name1 = namesql


# Функция кнопки "Зарегистрироваться"
    def rButton(self):

        errors = []
        # Проверки на пустоту заполнения полей
        if not name1:
            errors.append("Введите Ваше Имя и Фамилию")
            print(errors[0])
```

Comment: Изменил свой вопрос, всё равно ничего не работает

Comment: Не надо так делать в ООП.

Comment: @МаксимХалин, не удобно менять вопрос, когда к нему уже ответ - возникнет путаница. Хорошо бы было, когда бы вы вернули его до исходного состояния (нажмите на *"изменён ... часов назад"*) и ваш изменен вопрос задайте как *новый вопрос*.